# Reattach programs from crashed window manager

Tags: window-manager, gnome-shell

Sometimes when GNOME desktop crashes on me, the programs keep running headlessly.  While they're like that, some of them prevent new instances from being created once I've restarted the WM.

Is there a way for me to reattach these programs to the new GNOME instance?  Or is my only alternative to terminate them and start over (losing data and time)?

Comment: Do you get logged out when Gnome crashes? Ouch. What are the programs in question? The answer probably varies from program to program. You may want to disable 3D effects (disable Compiz), they're almost always the cause of such crashes.

Comment: @Gilles It sort of logs me out—it requires me to type my password but doesn't kill programs.  I don't use compiz and the programs range from gEdit to Firefox to a Geary.  Kinda weird.